# Can we recover the completion of a local ring $R$ if its associated graded is the coordinate ring of a Veronese variety?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, completion

Suppose $R$ is a localization of a normal closed point of a variety of dimension $n$ over an algebraically closed field $k$ with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. Suppose also that the associated graded $\operatorname{Gr}_{\mathfrak{m}} R$ is isomorphic to the degree $d$ Veronese subring $S_d$ of $k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$. Is this enough to conclude that the completion of $R$ is isomorphic to the completed local ring of $S_d$ at the origin? Are there counterexamples?